# Get github URL for most recent pushed commit

Tags: git, github

I have a pattern for pushing my commits to a dev branch in the simplified example below:

```
git status // Let's see what I did
git add . // I want to commit all my changes
git commit -m "I did a thing" // I commit with a message
git pull --rebase origin dev // I am trying to avoid a merge conflict
git status // I am really ready to push, right?
git push origin dev // I am pushing to github
```

Now I don't see anything wrong with the pattern (maybe I should?), but I want to quickly drop a link to the github URL of my commit elsewhere.

Ideal output, I guess would be something like changing this `git push` output:

```
To https://github.com/MyGithub/MyRepo
   aaa0001..aaa0000  dev -> dev
```

To

```
To https://github.com/MyGithub/MyRepo/path/to/latest/commit
   aaa0001..aaa0000  dev -> dev
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using `bash`? How about using the output of `git log` after pushing?

```
$ echo https://github.com/user/project/commit/$(git log --format="%H" -n 1)
https://github.com/user/project/commit/7e30ecbffa4ce37d0cb9e2d10682ce8fa0b24e4b
```